# Wondering about something regarding intermediate certificates and Weechat

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, weechat, certificate-authority

I have a private server at home that runs a node.js instance and weechat. I also have my own domain, which I registered at EuroDNS, as well as an AlphaSSL certificate, also from EuroDNS.

Both Weechat's relay protocol and node.js are set up to use TLS (node.js is configured to refuse HTTP requests, only HTTPS is allowed). What is strange is that I can access the node.js server through HTTPS without problems by using any HTTPS client. `openssl s_client` also works well. Weechat's relay protocol, however, doesn't. For some reason, when I try to open a TLS socket to it, it appears that the intermediate EuroDNS AlphaSSL CA certificate isn't sent out properly, because the clients report errors that they can't verify my domain's certificate. What's even weirder is that browsers do not seem to have this problem, since [Glowing Bear (HTML5 WeeChat relay client)](https://www.glowing-bear.org/) does not have this problem.

I had to manually copy the intermedia CA certificate .crt file to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and then run `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` to be able to open a TLS socket to the Weechat relay.

I used `openssl s_client -connect` to get some information. Here's what happens when I access the node.js server (slightly modified for privacy reasons):

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=example.com
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
```

And here is what happens if I try to open a TLS socket to Weechat's relay:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=example.com
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
---
```

If I read this correctly, then Weechat apparently isn't sending out the intermediate certificate, while node.js is. And this is probably not a problem in the browser, because it ships with that intermediate certificate. This would also explain why the problems with connecting to the relay vanish when I add the intermediate AlphaSSL certificate to the system's certificates.

Is my assumption correct? Does this mean that Weechat has a bug? I'm fairly new to CA's, certificates etc. so I am still learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, shortly after posting the question, I found the answer. I'm still keeping it here so others can learn from this.

The answer was that the .pem file that I added to weechat did have the two certificates chained, but there was an error - for unknown reasons, the intermediate certificate there was invalid. I recreated the chained .pem file with `cat my-domain.x509.crt intermediate.crt my-domain.priv.key > relay.pem`, and now it works fine.